# load function after page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to load a function after page load is completed?
I mean after rendering is completed or after the aspx file loaded i need to call a function:

```
void create_doc()
{
    create_word();
}
```

when loading the page Im assigning some values to lables.. After loading the page i need to read the whole page and save it into a word doc

Comment: what function?  what language?  also, format your code.

Comment: by "loading a function", do you mean "calling a function" ?

Comment: I have my own function 
create_doc()
{
}

Comment: Why exactly do you want to save your HTML to a doc? There should be Libraries for that btw.

Comment: @Simon I did that .. But i need to cal that function after page load is completed...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Unload`-stage, see the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: I have hardly seen Unload ever used though.

Comment: That is probably because HTTP is stateless, it is impossible for the server to know exactly when the browser did finish rendering. Since there is no "postback" when everything is viewable by the user.

What you can do is to have a Javascript that is fired at the bottom of your page that makes an async. call back to the server, notifying that the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanx Filip Ekberg  .. Can you give me a example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean calling a function, you would do:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
      create_doc();  
 }
```

or in the Page_Unload event as Filip pointed out.

Check the [Page.LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) event

Comment: He want to do it when the page is rendered, Page_Load is initated before rendering.

Comment: when loading the page Im assigning somme values to lables.. After loading the page i need to read the whole page and save it into a word doc